# White residue on circuit board

Tags: capacitor, pcb, short-circuit, induction, overheat

[image][image][image]What is this white powder on my induction cooker hob? Is is metal salt? The capacitor recently melted[image]

Comment: Was said capacitor physically close to these components? What does the melted  capacitor look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added the photo of the melted capacitor.

Comment: Is there a cooling fan that can intake dust from outside? The particles have a horizontal distribution pattern.

Comment: I just added the pic of the cooling fan. The powder doesnt look like dust, its white in color. The cooker is installed in the drawer.

Comment: I bet the cooling fan ever so slightly was touching "something" probably the metal box and got a bit shaved off of it.

Comment: That's not a melted cap.  It's probably some kind of glue the slobbered all over the inductor to hold it down physically.  SOmetimes those hum audibly, a little glue stops it.

Comment: @DBM Not an answer, but I can truthfully say that Lenovo returned a laptop to me that they were supposed to repair under warranty that had a lot less of that kind of powder in it (very little, really.) They said it might be ***anthrax*** and so returned it to me, refusing to repair it under warranty. Seriously. They actually said that. So there you go. Send it to the CDC for bio-weapon analysis. ;) Of course, reality is that there can be complex chemical reactions between flux, solvents, soldering, laminate and process issues like line speed and solder temp.

Comment: In the first photo, a grey-coloured box capacitor 4.7uf 275V at the extreme left *does look possibly damaged*. The gray/silver RTV right next to it, spilling into the toroid may be confusing things. Nothing to do with dusty residue.